# vscode show existing method documentation on hover

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vs code when i type a dot(.) and then a method a pop-up shows with the method definition.

my question is after i accept that method i no longer get the documentation and i might want to for example verify what the return value is of this particular method.

I have tried highlighting the method, ctrl-space on the method and googling for an answer with no luck

[image: this image shows the method documentation on first creation]

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+Space` for intellisense

`Ctrl+Shift+Space` to Trigger Parameter Hints

[VSCode Intellisense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)

Comment: thank you for your reply but this does not work for an existing method, only when i first trigger intellisence.  once method is accepted documentation goes away

Answer (score 1):

Few months after this post, today, I experienced the same issue and it turned out to be a problem in my way of commenting things. Here's the problematic code :

Let take to examples :

```js
class MyClass{
  /**
  *
  * @param {String} str     Only accepts strings
  * @returns {TypeError | this}
  *
  */
  method1(str){
    if(!int.isInteger()){
      return new TypeError("Type Error on method 1, only accepts strings")
    }
    return this
  }
}
```

We can agree that the method1 should return either a TypeError (if you pass it a string for example) OR an object of class MyClass (return this).

But when I use the .method1() later in my code and hover on, it only show my [any]. So what's wrong ? This line :

```
      * @returns {TypeError | this}
```

It looks like we can't do this so I found the solution :

```
      * @returns {this}
      * @throws {TypeError}
```

And it looks like this :

```js
class MyClass{
      /**
      *
      * @param {Number} int     Only accepts integers
      * @throws {TypeError} Only accepts an integer as parameter
      * @returns {this} Object of class MyClass
      *
      */
      method1(int){
        if(!int.isInteger()){
          return new TypeError("Type Error on MyClass.method1 : only accepts an integer as parameter")
        }
        return this
      }
}
```

Hope this answers to anyone who could have the same problem as @JesseBoyd and I. It was a quick fix actually.

Comment: this may work for your code but doesn't work for imported libraries.  and to clarify my tooltip goes away after I accept the autocomplete